# sketch the graph of whose equation is $(y-x+2)(2y+x-4)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I do not know what should I do. 
$y=x-2$ and $y=4-x/2$ and then sketch two lines?
or product two parantheses and then ı have like
$2y^2-x^2-xy+6x-8=0$

Comment: Yes, your equation defines two intersecting lines: $y=x-2$ and $y=2-x/2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From the null factor theorem you have worked out that: $y=x-2$ or $y=4-\frac{x}{2}$. So go and sketch both. Expanding is to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Since the product of $ y - x + 2 $ and $ 2y + x - 4 $ is zero, at least one of them must be zero. Therefore, the set of points satisfying your equation will be the union of the sets of points which make the factors zero. So yes, a diagram of both lines is the set of solutions to your equation.